# How to add image to kivy application?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm having trouble importing images into my kivy application. Here's the error log, and my code is below.

```
C:\Users\sangu\Desktop\LibertyComm>python main.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\sangu\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-09-09_57.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\sangu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.6rc1 (v3.6.6rc1:1015e38be4, Jun 12 2018, 07:51:23) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\sangu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.8141'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.8141'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file icons/unsplash2.jpg
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file icons/unsplash1.jpg
[WARNING] [Lang        ] kv/homescreen.kv has already been included!
[WARNING] [Lang        ] kv/settingscreen.kv has already been included!
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file icons/unsplash2.jpg
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error reading file icons/unsplash1.jpg
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

Here is my code:

```
#: import utils kivy.utils
<HomeScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: utils.get_color_from_hex("#FFFFFF")
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        GridLayout:
            rows: 1
            pos_hint: {"top": 1, "x": 1}
            size_hint: 1, .1
            Image:
                source: "icons/unsplash1.jpg"
                size: self.texture_size
```

I've been struggling with this for over an hour. Searching the web revealed absolutely nothing that worked, so hopefully, I'll be able to get a good response here. Thanks! (And yes, I'm sure the images are in the correct directory)

Comment: Do normal kivy buttons etc. look correct? If yes, that means basic image loading is working fine. Can you provide a minimal working example, e.g. just an App that displays an Image along with the image file that this app fails to load?

Comment: @inclement Yes, buttons look correct. Here is the [minimal working example](https://codeshare.io/ad1KzR).